# How can I delete every second line in avery big text file?

Tags: python-3.x, text, edit

I have a very big text file and I want to delete every second line. How can I do it in an effective way?

I have written a code like this:

```
_file = open("merged_DGM.txt", "r")
text = _file.readlines()
for i, j in enumerate(text):
    if i % 2 == 0:
       del text[i]

 _file.close()
 _file = open("half_DGM.txt", "w")
 for i in text:
    _file.write(i)

_file.close()
```

It works for small textfiles. but for big files, it loads the whole text into the variable. After 10 minutes it could not solve the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [file object returned by open iherits from io.IOBase and can be iterated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase). By directly iteration over the file you avoid loading your whole file into the memory at once.

```
with open("merged_DGM.txt", "r") as in_file and open("half_DGM.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for index, line in enumerate(in_file):
        if index % 2:
            out_file.write(line)
```